# Replace specific text with search input

Tags: javascript, api

I am using an API to view customer database and added a search button. The parameter and value that works when I test it is:

`filters:[{"field":"keyword_search","operator":"is","value":"Michael"}]`

my complete URL looks like this: https://www.mydomain.com/v1/objects/object_14/records/5648623548321?filters=%5B%7B%22field%22%3A%22keyword_search%22%2C%22operator%22%3A%22is%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22Michael%22%7D%5D

My goal is that when someone enters something in the search box and presses enter, the text they entered should simply replace the part that says: "Michael".

Is this possible with Javascript? Or is there a better way to do this? Essentially, the API does not supply me with a method of doing a search, instead I have to filter. But the filter requires the URL to have everything from [{"field....

Unless I'm mistaken, most paramaters are simply. ParameterName and Value. This one here is ParamaterName and value with other parameters.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: What have you tried so far? your *'code'* example makes no sense out of context

Comment: @musefan I am using Appery.io and it allows me to map a search box to a parameter. However, i can't map the search box to this parameter since the search text needs to go within a specific part of the paramater

Comment: @Moe if that is the case this is a bad question. Please update your question including the fact that the API is Appery.io and what you're doing with their api.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are adding multiple searches, so you could provide multiple inputs and at then end concat all of them.

```
<input type="text" name="filter[]" value="one" />
<input type="text" name="filter[]" value="two" />
<input type="text" name="filter[]" value="three" />
```

Then on submit you can turn those into your query string ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/icodeforlove/4ad5h/))

```
var filters = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[name="filter[]"]'));
filters = filters.map(function (filter) {
    return {"field":"keyword_search","operator":"is","value":filter.value};
});

console.log('filters=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(filters)));
```

Your question is kind of confusing because its not a simple search API its a filter API.